# What about the whetstone?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, equipment

In the Adventuring Gear section of the PHB, the whetstone is listed as an item. Yet it gets no description, game rules or anything. So, how does the whetstone work? What are the game rules that apply to it? And, in a more general term I suppose, what are rules for the decay and maintain of weapons?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are none, just like there are no rules for not wearing boots on the trail, not keeping your expensive parchment dry, or keeping the bugs out of your rations by packing them properly. All that stuff is roleplay and GM judgement.

No whetstone? "Clearly you are a bandit, sir! You claim to be a King's Man, but no reputable soldier would go around with a blade that looks as ill-used as *that*."

Note that not all players will appreciate this kind of slice-of-life detail. If you want these things to be important, talk about it with your players. If they scoff at having to buy a whetstone because there are no rules for needing them, either they're telling you that they want heroics and cinematically-ignoring the mundane details of adventuring, or they're just rules lawyering to justify being miserly. You know your players best and can judge which.

## Heroics

If they want movie-like heroics, tell them to buy an "adventurer's bundle" for *X* gp that has *Y* uses instead (set *X* and *Y* as you see fit), from which they can pull anything from climbing gear to tiny brass tripwire bells to whetstones to candles whenever they actually need it on-screen. They'll appreciate the streamlining of equipment, and you'll appreciate them being properly equipped when they should be.

I like this option because I've found that it simplifies things, while also making those moments when the PCs *do* need something like a whetstone actually more likely to happen on-screen. The players also become quite concerned about keeping their bundle topped up, so they pay willingly for it instead of grudgingly buying single items after lengthy arguments about it.

## Miserly

If they're just being miserly, feel free to reward their choice by giving its consequences screen time!

> "What's that? You're a warrior and scholar of wealth and good repute? No, I *won't* look in your filthy bag—which looks like it needs a washing as much as you do—just so you can prove that you could afford to care for your sword if you wanted. Clearly any wealth you have is stolen!"

Comment: *Pathfinder* rescue: "[Whetstone.](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/gear/adventuringGear.html#_whetstone) Price 2 cp; Weight 1 lb. A whetstone allows you to sharpen a blade by sliding it against the stone at a precise angle. Honing a blade with a whetstone requires about 15 minutes of work and grants the weapon a +1 bonus on your damage roll the first time you hit with it. This only works on nonmagical blades."

Comment: @sevensideddie loving the Dungeon World adventurer kit rules for the heroic suggestion.